# Implement notifyAll() and wait() for a particular key

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to multi-threading and have been looking at some tutorials to implement the same. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to use this for my problem statement.

I am implementing a notification system. I have a Key-Value database as my persistent layer. I have multiple clients requesting data for a particular key, and if they find the key is unavailable, they all enter a `wait()` state. Now I want to use `notifyAll()` whenever the value is available for the key [I will check the DB for the key to be available]. Since we pass an Object to the synchronised block, how can I pass the String key value in such a way that all the threads waiting for the particular key wakes up when it becomes available.

Any code example or tutorial will be appreciated to help me understand how I can implement the same.

Comment: It looks to me like using `wait()` and `notifyAll()` for this is the wrong approach. Those methods are low-level synchronization primitives, not a 'notification system'.

Comment: I want to basically implement a Push-based method which wakes up waiting clients when data is available. What else would you suggest for such a scenario?

Comment: Maybe use something like Project Reactor?

Comment: I looked into it but this Project Reactor looks like a complicated system to implement for a side-project. This will require extensive study and paradigm shift, but thanks for the suggestion!